# Редирект на php

Tags: .htaccess, php

Как сделать редирект с любого урла на какую-то одну страницу, чтобы при этом знать адрес который был запрошен изначально?

допустим пишут в url http://mysite.ru/blablabla
это все редиректится на http://mysite.ru/index.php, и там достаем http://mysite.ru/blablabla

Уточнение. Нужно сделать подобие http://goo.gl/, чтобы короткий урл на моем домене, типа http://mysite.ru/blablabla редиректил на внешний урл, который храниться в базе. Как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Создаем .htaccess с содержимым:

```
#RewriteEngine On
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-d
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-f
RewriteRule   ^(.*) redirect.php?%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Создаем файл redirect.php c содержимым

```
$dir_name = '/link'; //корневая дирректория
if(!empty($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'])) // Проверка на редирект
{
    $redirect = preg_replace("#$dir_name/#", "", $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']);     //получение параметра
    //дальше подключаем базу данный и ищем поле в таблице
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
    mysql_select_db("yourDbName",$conn);
    $sql = 'вид запроса';
    if (!($row = mysql_query($sql)))
    {
        print('SQL EROR');
    }
    if($row) //если поле найдено то выполняем редирект на url
    {
        $res = mysql_fetch_array($row);
        if(!empty($res['url']))
        {
            header("Location: {$res['url']}"); //$res['url'] - вывод после выполнения sql вашего поля с ссылками
        }else{
            header("Location: {$dir_name}/index.php"); 
                    exit;
        }
    }else{ //если поле не найдено то выполняем редирект на главную страницу
        header("Location: {$dir_name}/index.php"); 
            exit;
    }
}else{ //если редирект не найден
    header("Location: {$dir_name}/index.php"); 
    exit;
}
```

Надеюсь этот пример поможет, накинул от руки, так что возможны ошибки

Answer (score 2):

А ну так и сказали бы, вот направляете куда-то типа external.php ну там в htacces пропишите как перейти, в а скрипте сопоставляете свое blblabla с базой адресов и header('location: ваша внешняя ссылка');

Comment: http://anton.bukarev.org/web/sozdaem-servis-korotkix-ssylok/